# Find student with the maximum average mark

Tags: mysql, sql

i have tried a lot without success, i want to display only the maximum average of student marks from the  list of student as shown on the table below.

**My table**
[image]

i want to get the result as  below

**expected output**
[image]

**what i have done so far**

```
SELECT MAX(a.Total_Qty) As TotalMax,a.studentId
FROM(
SELECT AVG( s.marks ) AS Total_Qty,s.studentId
FROM results s
WHERE s.stream = 'Form One'
GROUP BY s.studentId) AS a
```

Comment: do you want the average note by student or for all students ?

Comment: i want to get one student with the maximum average

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inner query will give you the list of averages for each student.
Then we order (descending) by their average score and finally we get the top 1 (Limit 1)

```
SELECT  a.studentId, a.Total_Qty as MaxAvg
FROM(

   SELECT AVG( s.marks ) AS Total_Qty,s.studentId
   FROM results s
   WHERE s.stream = 'Form One'  
   GROUP BY s.studentId)

 AS a
 Order by a.Total_Qty Desc
 Limit 1
```

Alternatively:

```
   SELECT AVG( s.marks ) AS Total_Qty,s.studentId
   FROM results s
   WHERE s.stream = 'Form One'  
   GROUP BY s.studentId
   Order By AVG( s.marks ) Desc
   Limit 1
```

Comment: It seems that you can remove the query inclusion. Just sort by AVG(s.marks)

Answer (score -1):

**(UNTESTED) I hope it helps**

if you are using MSSQL :

```
SELECT TOP(1) studentId, AVG(marks) FROM results GROUP BY studentId
ORDER BY MAX(AVG(marks)) Desc
```

if you are using SQL :

```
SELECT studentId, AVG(marks) FROM results GROUP BY studentId
ORDER BY MAX(AVG(marks)) Desc Limit 0,1
```